# How do I solve a WSAECONNRESET error?

Tags: tcp, perforce, unreal-engine4

I am using Perforce as part of a small development team. Everyone was able to connect to the P4V client except for one person who gets the following error:

TCP receive failed.
read: socket: WSAECONNRESET

We have deactivated his McAfee firewall and virus scan, but the error persists. I really don't know what to do with this error and it seems to be rather undocumented on the perforce website. From what I gather, it's because it's not a perforce-specific issue, but rather a TCP communication problem that might be caused by something else.

Any tips?

Comment: Is the person with the problem able to use the 'p4' command line tool? Do they get this problem with the command line tool, or only with P4V?

Answer (score 2):

> a TCP communication problem that might be caused by something else.

This is possible, or it's possible that whenever this user connects it causes some sort of server fault.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668.aspx

> **WSAECONNRESET 10054** Connection reset by peer.
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

Beyond the usual connection troubleshooting questions (is this user on the same subnet?  same version of the client software?  same exact P4PORT setting?  is the user able to connect via the command line client and if not does it give a more helpful error?  why is this user unlike all other users?) I'd look at the server logs to see if it's logging any sort of more helpful error when this user tries to connect.

Comment: Turns out our user was unable to connect to perforce from school, but could on his own private network. It isn't much of a problem as most work would be done from home, but I would still like to solve it. Any idea?

In any case, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: My guess is that the school network is blocking port 1666, or doing some sort of packet-inspection-based filtering to block unknown programs.