# C socket partial http download

Tags: c, http, download, winsock, recv

I'm trying to write a C program that will download a remote file from the URL provided without using any libraries like curl/libcurl. I've implemented recvAll() and sendAll() functions because I know TCP only guarantees ordered packets. I parse the headers to get the expected file size from Content-Length and then keep decrementing the bytes left by receiving either the chunk size or the remaining bytes. The problem is that files being downloaded sometimes are up to tens of KB off because the connection is closed prematurely for some reason. (recv() returns -1). Smaller files that are a few kilobytes work.
I'm on gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1) using winsock2.

I already wrote a similar working version of this in python using streams and by sending the same HTTP GET request, and parsing using the same methods. I've also tried receiving the response headers byte by byte by memcpy()ing to another buffer and searching for index of closing \r\n inside the response. (I've written a TCP file transfer server/client in Linux before and an older recv() would cut off some bytes because the buffer was waiting to be filled, so receiving 1 byte at a time was a quick test to determine if some buffer is incomplete.) I also tried adding an Accept header or keep-alive connection.

```c
int receiveFile(SOCKET sock, char filename[])
{ 
    int fileLen; // length of file, taken from http response
    int write_sz; // write size
    int received; // counter of received bytes
    char response[1024]; // http response will go here
    int pos; // for index of \r\n\r\n
    int torecv; // to recv chunk or remaining
    char * buf = (char *)malloc(8192);
    received = recvAll(sock, buf, 1024);
    pos = getIndexOfDelimiter(buf);
    strncpy(response, buf, pos+4); // copy buf to response up to the index of \r\n\r\n
    int respLen = strlen(response) -4; // not counting CLRF
    fileLen = getContent_Length(response);
    printf("Expecting %d bytes of data.\n", fileLen);
    FILE *fs = fopen(filename, "wb+");
    if (fileLen < 1024-respLen) { // for files < 1024 
        write_sz = fwrite(&buf[pos+4], sizeof(char), fileLen, fs); 
        if (write_sz < fileLen) {
            printf("Couldn't write all data.");
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        write_sz = fwrite(&buf[pos+4], sizeof(char), 1024-respLen, fs);
    }
    fileLen -= write_sz;
    while (fileLen > 0) 
    {
        torecv = min(8192, fileLen); // recv min(chunk, leftovers)
        printf("%d\n", torecv);
        int state = recvAll(sock, buf, torecv);
        if (state == -1) {
            printf("Connection closed for some reason...\n");
            break;
        }
        write_sz = fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), torecv, fs);
        if (write_sz < torecv) {
            printf("Couldn't write all data.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        fileLen -= torecv;
    } 
    fclose(fs);
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
char * requestBuilder(char *path) // GET request builder
{
    char * request = malloc(1024);
    request[0] = '\0';
    strcat(request, "GET /");
    strcat(request, path);
    strcat(request, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ");
    strcat(request, "www.mywebsite.com");
    strcat(request, "\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla 5.0\r\n\r\n");
    return request;
}
int recvAll(int socket, char *buf, int len) { // recvAll function
 int remaining = len;

 while (remaining) {
    int received = recv(socket, buf, remaining, 0);
    if (received <= 0) return -1;

    buf += received;
    remaining -= received;
 }
    return 0;
}
```

The error happens where recv() returns -1 after some point even though there's still many bytes to be received.

Comment: Usually any POSIX networking code has a `select` call at the core of its event loop, but I don't see this here. You're just slamming ruthlessly against `recv`, as many times per second as you possibly can, which is extremely inefficient. You're going to pin a core here doing nothing.

Comment: @tadman I think this is a blocking socket.

Comment: What do the docs for `recv` say to do when it returns -1? There's very little error checking and reporting in this code. Which `recv` returns -1 first?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the recv in recvAll() returns -1 eventually, and it is a blocking socket. (non-blocking in C is something I will try later after this).

Comment: @JohnChristoforidis The first `recvAll` or the second? How many bytes of data was expected? How many were received?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's a good observation if true, but that's a different flavour of messy.

Comment: I'm downloading an image that's 640 KB, it usually downloads anywhere from 540 to 620 so it's more than just a few recvAll calls. The check if (write_sz < torecv) makes sure we wrote the amount we expected. It should be receiving either a chunk which I've chosen to be 8192 or the remaining size by using min()

Comment: @tadman I'm happy with making it non-blocking if it makes our life much easier.

Comment: `int respLen = strlen(response) -4;` That terrifies me. You have `pos`, why call `strlen`? Are you sure the `response` is null terminated?

Comment: Also, if this is code that you are relying on for a real world application, please don't do that. Use a sensible HTTP client library. There are a million reasons this kind of code can fail. For example, you claim HTTP 1.1 compliance and you don't support chunked encoding. But the HTTP 1.1 specification says clients MUST support chunked encoding.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I used strlen(response) because of strncpy(response, buf, pos+4) which copies buf to response up to position of \r\n\r\n (including it), should I add a '\0' at the end? I am not planning to use this in any real world application as I am aware of the limitations and flaws it can have. I'm familiar with sockets but I'm a new programmer in C.

Comment: @JohnChristoforidis Don't use `strlen` when you already know the length. Maybe there's a zero byte embedded in the response. Who knows. Why make it complicated?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that's a good point, I fixed it so it saves us from a headache later, I shouldn't have assumed that the response headers are only clear text.

Comment: I opened a complete download and the partial download in "rb" from the python interpreter and I determined this:
```>>> partial,full = open("image.jpg", "rb").read(), open("file.jpg", "rb").read()
>>> full[:len(partial)] == partial
True
>>>```

Comment: "*`if (received <= 0) return -1;`*" you want to distinguish between 0 and <1. 0 means the peer closed the connection. <1 means an error occured. In this latter case do a `perror("recv() failed")` right after you detected it  *inside* `recvAll()` to learn what went wrong.

Comment: If on Windows use `GetLastError()` instead of `perror()`.

Comment: @alk I am getting error code 10054 edit:
WSAECONNRESET
10054

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371283/694576

Comment: I turned off my antivirus to make sure it isn't blocking the remote server and also tried a different website (imgur) to fetch the file from. As mentioned in my post I have made a python version of this which uses the same GET request and always works from the same network.

Comment: `select`-driven code is sort of the true power of POSIX networking. This allows your process to juggle many different things within the same thread very efficiently. An evolution of `select` is things like kqueue/epoll which build on the same idea and make it even more scalable, but it uses the same principles.

Comment: @tadman I'm planning to use IOCP after I get the hang of blocking sockets in C

Comment: If `recv()` returns `0` (meaning the peer gracefully closed the connection) then your `recvAll()` wrapper returns `-1`, indicating an error. if you go into the 8K read loop and the remainder of the file length is not a multiple of 8K you'll lose data.